# Referencing Results of Multiple Temporary Tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, subset

I’m using SQL Server 2008

I have joins written something like the following, where the first join is encapsulated in a ‘With as’ statement so that I can name the output table as ‘A’ and then reference the ‘A’ resulting table in the next select and Join seen beneath it.

This works perfectly fine. What I would like to do then is reference that second table for another select statement and join, but when I try to wrap it in a ‘With as’ statement as well, the editor does not accept it as legitimate syntax for the second instance of 'With as'.

How can I subset resulting tables to reference in further select and join statements? I do not have permission to write to the database, so I can not create permanent tables in the database.

Thank you.

```
With A as
(
SELECT POL.[COMPANY_CODE]
      ,POL.[POLICY_NUMBER]
      ,POL.[STATUS_CODE]
      ,POL.ORIG_CLIENT_NUM 
      ,TA.LINE 

 FROM [SamsReporting].[dbo].[POLICY] POL

 Left join [SamsReporting].[dbo].[Transact] TA
 ON TA.POLICY_NUMBER = POL.POLICY_NUMBER and TA.BASE_Account = 'B' 
)


 Select PM.POLICY_NUMBER
       ,A.[COMPANY_CODE]
      ,A.[POLICY_NUMBER]
      ,A.[Policy Status]
      ,eApp.SourceCode



  From A

Left Join Web.dbo.Pmetrics PM on A.POLICY_NUMBER=PM.POLICY_NUMBER

Left Outer Join DDP.pol.eAppStaging eApp
on A.POLICY_NUMBER=eApp.PolicyNumber

where eApp.SourceCode = 'HAQ' or eApp.SourceCode = 'PLS'
```

Answer (score 2):

Common Table Expressions (CTEs) can build upon each other as you would like. For example, you can do this:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT * FROM Table 1)
, CTE2 AS (SELECT * FROM CTE1)
, CTE3 AS (SELECT * FROM CTE2)
```

You only need the WITH statement for the first CTE. After that just use the CTE name, as in my example.

Hope that helps,

Ash

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a syntax issue to me. Google CTE (Common Table Expression) and review some examples of how they are formed.

```
With A as
     (SELECT POL.[COMPANY_CODE]
      ,POL.[POLICY_NUMBER]
      ,POL.[STATUS_CODE]
      ,POL.ORIG_CLIENT_NUM 
      ,TA.LINE 

      FROM [SamsReporting].[dbo].[POLICY] POL
      Left join [SamsReporting].[dbo].[Transact] TA
          ON TA.POLICY_NUMBER = POL.POLICY_NUMBER and TA.BASE_Account = 'B'),
     B as (
      Select PM.POLICY_NUMBER
       ,A.[COMPANY_CODE]
       ,A.[POLICY_NUMBER]
       ,A.[Policy Status]
       ,eApp.SourceCode  
      From A
      Left Join Web.dbo.Pmetrics PM on A.POLICY_NUMBER=PM.POLICY_NUMBER
      Left Outer Join DDP.pol.eAppStaging eApp
         on A.POLICY_NUMBER=eApp.PolicyNumber
      where eApp.SourceCode = 'HAQ' or eApp.SourceCode = 'PLS')

Select *
From B -- inner join some table
where some condition = 1
```

Comment: Ash and RwKing, thank you both. I think removing the second with and adding the comma in between solved it for me.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept one as the answer so the question will close.

Comment: No problem @LionRunner